# By using proof by cases, prove that if x is real number such that (x² - 1)/(x + 2) > 0, then either x > 1 or -2 < x < -1.

Tags: logic, solution-verification

For case x > 1

x² > 1
→ x² -1 > 0 -----(1)

x + 2 > 1 + 2
→ x + 2 > 3 -----(2)

(1)/(2)
(x² -1)/(x + 2) > 0/3
(x² -1)/(x + 2) > 0
Therefore case x > 1 statement is true.

For case -2 < x < -1

- -2 < x < -1
  → 2 > x > 1
  → 4 > x² > 1
  → 3 > x²- 1 > 0 -----(1)
- -2 < x < -1
  → 2 > x > 1
  → 4 > x + 2 > 3 -----(2)

(1)/(2)
3/4 > (x²- 1)/(x + 2) > 0/3
→3/4 > (x²- 1)/(x + 2) > 0
Therefore (x²- 1)/(x + 2) > 0  is true for case - 2 < x < -1

Therefore the statement is true for both two cases.
Therefore if x is real number such that (x² - 1)/(x + 2) > 0, then either x > 1 or  -2 < x < -1.

Is this correct? Are there other ways to it?

Answer (score 1):

The proof is correct.

An alternate way to prove it is,
$$f(x)=\dfrac{x^2-1}{x+2}=\dfrac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x+2)}$$

The critical points are $1,-1,-2$. Since the coefficients of $x$ are positive, the above equation can only be $<0$ when all $3$ brackets are negative or only of them is negative.

From this it is easy to note that iff $-1<x<1$ or $x\in(-\infty,-2)$ the value of $f(x)$ is negative and iff $x>1$ or $-2<x<-1$ then $f(x)$ is positive.

This is from [Wavy Curve Method](https://brilliant.org/wiki/wavy-curve-method/#:%7E:text=The%20wavy%20curve%20method%20(also,%5Cleq%200%5Cright).)

Comment: Thank you very much!